# When the denominator is larger than the numerator, why does the modulo equal the numerator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, calculator

As an example, why does 1 modulo 2 equal 1?

According to Google's [built-in calculator](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=1%20%25%202):

```
1 % 2 = 1

5 % 40 = 5

12 % 2000 = 12
```

Why is the remainder not "0", "error", or something?

In other words, I don't follow the mathematical reasoning:

Why is the remainder of `5 % 40` set as `5` itself, when, in fact, there is no positive integer (whole-number) remainder, e.g. `5/40 = 0.125`?

Comment: Do you know the definition of remainder? If you take 27 modulo 5, then the remainder is 2, and not 5 (which is 27/5 rounded down).

Comment: @N.U., yes, I do. Not sure where you got `27 % 5` from, **I'm asking about cases where the denominator is larger than the numerator**

Comment: Well, that does not really matter. It is exactly the same rule whether or not the integer part is 0 or 5. $2 \, \% \, 5$ is also equal to 2. You do modulo calculations every day, since a day is 24 hours, but one always says what the clock is modulo 12 (6:00 and 18:00 are 6 AM and 6 PM respectively).

Comment: @N.U., so *why* does the modulo remainder equal the numerator itself in these cases?

Comment: It is straight from the definition, and not different from the other cases. For the case 5 modulo 40, we have that $5 = 0 \cdot 40 + 5$, so the remainder is 5. Maybe it would help if you could write down your definition of remainder, since it looks like you don't have the correct definition. But if you take a look at the answers, everything is thoroughly explained.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: @N.U., thanks, I've seen the definitions in mathematical notation, but I was hoping for the plain-English definition that highlights the cases in my question; because, as of now, I see it as: "the modulo ... operation finds the remainder of division of one number by another"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The remainder when $1$ is divided by $2$ is $1$, since $1=(0)(2)+1$ and $0\le 1\lt 2$.

In general, if $0\le a\lt m$ then $a\operatorname{\%}m=a$.

In general, when you divide an integer $a$ by a positive integer $m$, there is a **quotient** $q$ and a **remainder** $r$. So 
$$a=qm+r,$$
where $0\le r\lt m$.

For instance, if $a=30$ and $m=12$, then $q=2$ and $r=6$. If $a=5$ and $m=12$, then $q=0$ and $r=5$.

In the case where $a=1$ and $m=2$, the quotient is $0$ and the remainder is $1$.

**Remark:** It is useful to have concrete images to go along with more abstract descriptions. Suppose that we have a box that contains $a$ cookies, and we have $m$ kids in the room. We give a cookie to everyone (if we can). Then we do it again, and again, doing a **full** round each time. The number of cookies left in the box is the remainder when $a$ is divided by $m$, it is what's left over.

For example, if $a=40$ and $m=12$, we do $3$ full rounds, each kid gets $3$ cookies. This $3$ is called the *quotient*. We will have $4$ cookies left over, the remainder is $4$, in symbols $40\operatorname{\%} 12=4$. If we start with $72$ cookies, the remainder is $0$.

But if we start with $5$ cookies, then we can't even get started, we cannot distribute cookies without causing a riot. So the quotient is $0$, nobody gets a cookie. And all the cookies are left over, the remainder is $5$, that is, $5\operatorname{\%}12=5$.

Comment: But why, based on the underlying quantitative mathematical concepts, is that the case?

Comment: Using a calculator, here is how you find the remainder when the positive number $a$ is divided by $m$. (1) Use the calculator to divide as usual. So for $a=47$ and $m=25$ I get $1.88$. (2) **Throw away** (subtract) the part in front of the decimal point. so I get $0.88$. (3) Multiply by $m$. I get $22$. But it is better to think of remainder as follows. Subtract $m$ from $a$ until you can't subtract any more without getting a negative answer. what's **left** is the **remainder**. If we start with $a=5$ and $m=12$, we can't subtract at all, so what's left (the remainder, $5\%12$) is just $5$.

Comment: Think of it in terms of cookies. You have $40$ cookies, $12$ people. You give a cookie to everybody until you cant't do a full round anymore. What's left in the box is the remainder. There will be $4$ cookies left, so $40\%12=4$. If you start with $12$ people, $5$ cookies, you can't give a cookie to everybody, so the remainder is $5$.

Comment: What if the cookie is set to expire in 3 days, can you then give that same cookie to the next person? (So is there where Einstein's theories of space-time come into play?)

Comment: So, does that mean that the answer is: the remainder is the numerator because it is simply not being divided?

Comment: I am weak on Physics, and no expert on cookie distribution. And yes, what you described in your next comment is a reasonable way of viewing it.

Comment: Thanks, can you work that into the answer — mathematically, of course? (FTAOD: I was joking with the browser cookies and physics.)

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe you've not fully understood the modulo operator. Maybe this picture will help:

[image]

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt: I understand what the modulo is; especially in cases like the example you gave, 9 % 2 = 1, where there is a remainder (even if it's zero). **My question refers to cases where division does not result in a zero or whole-number remainder.**

Answer (score 2):

> 1 % 2 = 1

What remains after all the times 2 goes into 1 (which is no times), is 1.

> 5 % 40 = 5

What remains after all the times 40 goes into 5 (which is no times), is 5.

> 12 % 2000 = 12

What remains after all the times 2000 goes into 12 (which is no times), is 12.

Comment: perfect explanation

Answer (score 1):

Because; ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

[image]

See the space where I gave it a green $0$. For a while consider there is nothing written. What number $\color{green}{n}$ could we put there such that after multiplying by $\color{red}{2}$, say $\color{red}{2}\color{green}{n}$, a substraction  $1-\color{red}{2}\color{green}{n}$ makes sense? Search it.... The common number for $\color{green}{n}$ could be $\color{green}{0}$. Now I think, you can make this way generalized for other case.

Comment: Could you please explain what the table means? I have never seen anything like it before.

Comment: @TomOldfield: It is not a special or a new thing. I am just pointing what others cited theoretically by colors.

Answer (score 1):

the remainder is how much you add to the product in order to get back to the numerator (assuming these values are ints)

so, for 5 % 40........

numerator = 5

5 / 40 = 0

product = 0

product + remainder = numerator

0 + remainder = 5

remainder = 5

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.

Answer (score 0):

$$1\equiv b \mod 2 \to b-1=2k :k\in\mathbb Z , 0\le b\le2 $$ only $b=1$ satisfy in $b-1=2k :k\in\mathbb Z , 0\le b\le2 $

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion happens because faulty logic that if something can be divided in even parts there should be no remainder (at least that was my first faulty thought which caused me to look at this a littler closer)
For example, I reasoned if $10$ can be divided by $2$ and result in $0$ as remainder, that should apply to $\frac12$ where by dividing $1$ into two equal pieces we have nothing left.

Though it is true that $1$ can be divided by $2$ in perfectly equal parts of $\frac12$ but that is not the definition of remainder.
One way to think of a remainders is that it is whatever is left when the divisor becomes larger than leftover of a dividend. E.g. $\frac{23}2 = 11$ quotient and $1$ remainder. (since $23-22 = 1$ and $1$ as the current dividend is smaller than $2$ the divisor it becomes the remainder)
In cases of any smaller number divided by a larger number, the smaller number (dividend) by being smaller automatically equals the remainder. Thus $12.5 \% 15000 = 12.5$ or $1 \% 2 = 1$.  In other words we can't divide into fractions less than the divisor.
One   more way to think about this is that  division is basically a repeated subtraction of one number from another. At some point the number can't   be further subtracted   as a whole   while still resulting  in a   positive  number.  whatever  that leftover is  , is the remainder.